# setState with arrow function does not work

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Could you please have a look on the following code. I need to get some value from another class. This works asynchronous, so I provided a function `handleGameDeserialization`.
The function gets the right value (as I tested with the alert), however the setState function has no impact. Could that be a "this-context" issue?

```
export default class GameplayScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.fbGame = new FBGame();

      global.currentScreenIndex = 'Gameplay';

      this.state = {
        currentGame: 'N/A'
      }
      // this.handleGameDeserialization = this.handleGameDeserialization.bind(this);

      if (this.props.route.params != null) {
          this.gameKey = this.props.route.params.gameKey;
          this.game = this.fbGame.deserializeGame(this.gameKey, this.handleGameDeserialization);
      }
  }

  handleGameDeserialization = (game) => {
      //  alert('yeah'+game);   // here comes the expected output

      this.setState({
          currentGame: game
        });
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text>{this.state.currentGame}</Text>
        </View>
        /*<Board game={this.state.game}/>*/
      )
  }
}
```

I call that function when the component GameplayScreen is navigated to. As you can see above, there is a class FBGame, which does the deserialization (read the game from firebase database)

```
export default class FBGame {
    ...
    deserializeGame(key, handleGameDeserialization) {
       var gameRef = firebase.database().ref("games/"+key).child("serialized");
       gameRef.on("value", snapshot => {
            //console.log('deserialized: ' + );
            handleGameDeserialization(snapshot.val().serialized);

       });
    }
    ...
}
```

edit:

When I use componentDidMount like below, it works fine. But this seems to be an anti-pattern. I still don't understand, why it doesn't work, when callded in the constructor and how I am supposed to solve this.

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.game = this.fbGame.deserializeGame(this.gameKey, this.handleGameDeserialization);
  }
```

Comment: Where do you call that function?

Comment: I call it from the constructor of the GameplayScreen. I added more information to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For things like subscriptions that will update the state and other side-effects, you should put the logic out in `componentDidMount()` which will fire immediately after the component is mounted and won’t give you any trouble if you update the state inside of it.
You can't but things that call `this.setState` in the constructor.